# provide read and write table locking in mysql

Tags: mysql, concurrency, locking, innodb, myisam

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE `uli` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The table shall always contain one value in one row. But it could be changed often. I would like to make a select, lock the table for other connections, update a value and the unlock.
For example, the following code works excellent:

```
LOCK TABLES uli WRITE;
SELECT * FROM uli;
UPDATE uli SET id=id+1;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

While first connection do not unlock, all other connection will wait, and only after unlock could see new value. That is exactly what I want. Is it exists some more elegant solution? Does it matter MyIsam or Innodb table to use?

Answer (score 0):

You are locking for write, which means selects will still see the old value before the update. Also you are not doing anything with your select. If you use InnoDB and SERIALIZABLE isolation level, all you need is the update statement.